# Failure using dplyr::tbl to reference PostgreSQL (Amplitude analytics) table

Tags: r, postgresql, dplyr, amplitude-analytics

I'm unable to connect to a PostgreSQL table (amplitude analytics) using this dplyr approach:

```
dplyr::tbl(amplitude_db, from = "app123.myEvent") %>% show_query()
```

Output:

```
 RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  relation "app123.myEvent" does not exist
```

However, this approach works:

```
dplyr::tbl(myCon,sql(("SELECT * FROM app123.myEvent"))) %>% show_query()
```

Output:

```
<SQL>
SELECT * FROM app123.myEvent
>
```

Any ideas why the first approach is failing?

Answer (score 2):

I think your first approach can work if you use `in_schema` from package `dbplyr`:

```
tbl(myCon, in_schema("app123", "myEvent")) %>% show_query()
```

If you know you're going to query multiple tables from the same schema `app123`, it can be a good idea to set the search path to this schema:

```
dbSendQuery(myCon, "set search_path to app123")
```

(this way you won't need to specify the schema each time)

Answer (score 0):

Amplitude support pointed me here, it's a known issue:
https://github.com/rstats-db/RPostgres/issues/32